# Mann-Whitney Table

Tags: self-study

Reading a Mann-Whiteny table and the median lable is written as "Median(0-33)". What does that (0-33) mean?[image]

Comment: pls include description of Table 3 from paper and citation

Comment: There were 33 items in the assessment (Section 3.4.3). The (0-33) indicates the possible values for the median, giving a context to the number.

Comment: Thanks Edward Carney. How did you pull up the paper to refer section 3.4.3? My guess was that the possible outcome can only be 0-33; so I was kinda on the right tract. Wanted to confirm. AdamO, I only have this section of the paper, therefore couldn't even pull up the paper to read the full description of the experiment. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Please offer a full reference for context. Please note also that "A Mann-Whitney table" is not a specific thing in statistics -- the term does not  convey what the table you're looking at actually has in it. You have here a *table in a paper* which presents some summary statistics on three variables across two groups, and some test statistics and p-values for the three variables, and what looks like a range of possible values for these variables (but without more context it's hard to be 100% certain -- hence the need for a proper reference).

Comment: Full contents of section 3.4.3 as answer.

Comment: The use of this to others appears to hinge on how far they have exactly the same question about exactly the same detail in a paper that isn't even fully referenced! Downvoting as not useful (to others).

Answer (score 2):

There were 33 items in the assessment (Section 3.4.3). The (0-33) indicates the possible values for the median, giving a context to the number.

Accessed through University of Minnesota library.

3.4.3.
Research participation questionnaire
This tool reflected the nurses’ participation in research
activities over the most recent 3 yr. The research
activities included creation of research plans, reference
retrieval, collection and analysis, research report writing,
participation in symposiums, and research paper
publishing. The contents in the questionnaire were made
by Tsai et al. (1998b) in accordance with Taylor and
Mitchell (1990), Wells and Baggs (1994), Pettengill et al.
(1994), Rizzuto et al. (1994), and Hicks (1995). It was
further modified according to the opinions of eight
experts. The KR-20 was 0.91, indicating a good internal
consistency for this tool. There were 12 research
activities in the tool. Five of the items contained 5–10
minor items each for a total of 33 items. A 2-point
scoring system was adopted in which 1 meant participation
in such research activity and 0 meant no participation.
A higher score meant more participation in
research activities.

Comment: What is this? Is this supposed to be an answer to the posted question? How?

Comment: Note the fifth comment to the original question. Questioner wanted to know about the original paper, because she/he had no access to the original. There was no room to put this in the comment, so this had to do. Sorry you got confused.

Comment: As I understand it, this boils down to saying that the possible values for the variable concerned run from 0 to 33, so that is the context in which to think about the medians. The answer has nothing to do with Mann-Whitney as such, just the original data.

Comment: The actual answer to this question appears to be your first comment. Why not add that at the top of this, with this info below it for context? Then this Q could be officially answered. (Thanks for clarifying, BTW.)